# How can I extract date and time from php variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a quastion.
 So I get from server a variable with date-time string which looks like this: '31/08/2015 13:24'.
  How can extract from this string separately date and time?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string:

```
var dateTime = '31/08/2015 13:24'.split(" ");
console.log(dateTime[0]); //date
console.log(dateTime[1]); //time
```

Or use js [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object to get the day, month, year, hours, etc:

```
var dateTime = new Date('31/08/2015 13:24');
```

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)